# How does this core.match binding example work?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.match

See this [example](https://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Basic-usage#binding):

```clojure
(let [x 1 y 2]
  (match [x y]
    [1 b] b
    [a 2] a
   :else nil))
;=> 2
```

I can't get my head around a few things:

1. Does `1` match `x` and gets bound to `b`?
2. Does `2` match `y` and gets bound to `a`?
3. Assuming I got the two points above right, why return `a` instead of `b` considering they both matched part of `[x y]`. Is it because it is the last clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of each pattern as a template to be matched to the input `[x y]` or `[1 2]`.

The first pattern is `[1 b]` which matches the input because the first template item is a  matching literal value `1`, and the second template item is a *binding* that will hold *any* value in that position of the input, which happens to be `2` in this case. That `b` binding is accessible from the righthand side of the match clause, as if it were a `let` binding.

This example might demonstrate it more clearly:

```
(let [x 1 y 2]
  (match [x y]
    [1 b] [1 (inc b)] ;; recreate the input with (inc b)
    [a 2] a           ;; this never matches because prior match works
    :else nil))
=> [1 3]
```

> Does `2` match `y` and gets bound to `a`?

The pattern is a match, but it doesn't matter because the preceding pattern was already a match. If it were the successful match, `a` would be bound to `1`.

Comment: So I guess I was wrong to say that, in the 2nd clause, `a` was bound to `2`.